# Outputting HTML in PHP - the HTML is not being output where it is supposed to

Tags: php, html

I have this kind of HTML structure (stripped down for easy readability):

```
<head>
<title>My website!</title>
<?php include "myFile.php"; ?>
</head>

...

<div id="header"></div>
<div id="content">
  <?php GetSomeStuff(); ?>
</div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

And then I have the myFile.php:

```
<?php
  ob_start();
   function GetSomeStuff()
   {
     if(something)
      {
      ob_end_clean();
      ?>
        <p>some html here!</p>
      <?php
      ob_start();
      }
   }
  ob_end_clean();
?>
```

We expect that our HTML will now look like:

```
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="content">
  <p>some html here!</p>
</div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

Well, guess what. This is what it looks like:

```
<p>some html here!</p>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

Not only does it insert the p tag at the beginning of the body tag, but it also removes my beautiful header and content divs! Also, my header tag is empty - no title! :(

Obviously I am doing something wrong. How can I do this correctly? Please note that the output is gonna be a tad bigger than what I posted here. ;)

Comment: Apart of your problem: For me quite useful was the answer to [To echo or not to echo?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2216893/237483).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your myFile.php should be as follows:

```
<?php
  ob_start();
   function GetSomeStuff()
   {
     if(something)
      {
      ?>
        <p>some html here!</p>
      <?php
      }
   }
  ob_end_clean();
?>
```

Comment: BAM! Right on! I didnt think it would output it when the output buffer was started :P

Comment: Just did - had to wait 3 minutes :P

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php
  ob_start();
   function GetSomeStuff()
   {
     if(something)
      {
      ob_end_clean();
      echo "<p>some html here!</p>";
      ob_start();
      }
   }
  ob_end_clean();
?>
```

Comment: I thought about that, but when I want to output multiple lines without having to escape anything in the HTML, it wont do :(

Comment: What do you mean? why do you need to output several lines? for readability of the code? just put everything in one line ...

`echo "<p>some html here!</p><p>even more stuff</p><p><img src='myimage.jpg'></p>";`

Comment: Yes, and to avoid having to escape the "".

Comment: Well another way around this is to properly style another file, i.e. yourcodetobeinserted.html and include it instead of echoing it ...

Comment: Or instead of the "one line" use the [herodoc syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216893/php-to-echo-or-not-to-echo/2216908#2216908)

Answer (score 0):

Try ECHOing the HTML in you PHP-file. Apart from that probably causing the behaviour you're seeing, it's pretty bad style switching between PHP and HTML in a PHP-file - especially when separating PHP from HTML is something that you're trying to do.

Did you think about using a template engine like Smarty?
 http://www.smarty.net/

Comment: I am doing that because I will be outputting a lot of HTML, and I do not want to do \n for a newline, to make sure the HTML looks proper.

Comment: Smarty looks like it is a mess to install :)

Comment: You don't have to use \n for a new line, you can just use linebreaks in your HTML-code. Can't show in comment, will post a new answer. EDIT: I don't know, if Smarty is a "mess to install", but your code will definitely be a mess without it :)

Answer (score 0):

> I am doing that because I will be outputting a lot of HTML, and I do
>   not want to do \n for a newline, to make sure the HTML looks proper.

Try this:

```
echo "<p>
  some text
</p>";
```

And you will have "proper HTML" without using "\n".